Which of these is $\text{null}(A \otimes B)$?
If $A\in \mathrm{Mat}_{n,m}(F)$ and $B \in \mathrm{Mat}_{p,q}(F)$ where $F$ is a field, then
$$
A\otimes B \in \mathrm{Mat}_{np,mq}(F), \quad A\otimes B=(a_{i_1,j_1}b_{i_2,j_2}) ,\quad \begin{array}{c}
 1\leq i_1\leq n, 
1\leq j_1\leq m,\\1\leq i_2 \leq p,1\leq j_2\leq q.\end{array}
$$
is the Kronecker product of $A$ and $B$. For $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n,m}(F)$ we write $\mathrm{null}(A)$ for the kernel of $A$, that is, $\{v \in F^m: A.v=0\}$.
I read in a book that $$\text{null} (A \otimes B)= \text{span} \{ v \otimes w : v \in \text{null}(A) , w \in \text{null}(B) \},$$ but I think it should be $$\text{null} (A \otimes B)= \text{span} \{ v \otimes w : v \in \text{null}(A) \ \text{or} \ w \in \text{null}(B) \}.$$ Am I wrong or this is a mistype in the book?

What are $A$ and $B$?

What is $\operatorname{null}$?

You are correct.
It is obvious that $\ker(A \otimes B)\supseteq\operatorname{span}\{ v \otimes w :\ v \in \ker(A) \ \text{or} \ w \in \ker(B) \}$. Using the identity $\operatorname{rank}(A\otimes B)=\operatorname{rank}(A)\operatorname{rank}(B)$ and the rank-nullity theorem, one also sees that the two subspaces have equal dimensions. Hence they are equal.
The linear span $\operatorname{span}\{ v \otimes w :\ v \in \ker(A) \ \text{and} \ w \in \ker(B) \}$ is not a correct answer, because it has a smaller dimension in general. E.g. when $A=I$ and $B=0$, this linear span is zero, but $\ker(I\otimes0)$ is nonzero.

In terms of linear maps, the statement is that if $\alpha\colon V_1\to W_1$ and $\beta\colon V_2 \to W_2$ are linear maps, then $\alpha\otimes \beta \colon V_1\otimes V_2 \to W_1\otimes W_2$ has
$$
\ker(\alpha\otimes\beta) = \ker(\alpha)\otimes V_2 +V_1\otimes \ker(\beta).
$$
user1551's answer is probably the most efficient way to show this in the finite-dimensional case. The proof below works (assuming the axiom of choice) for arbitrary vector spaces, but it also establishes the identity $\mathrm{rank}(A\otimes B) = \mathrm{rank}(A).\mathrm{rank}(B)$. Essentially, the argument is as follows: by bilinearity it is clear that $\ker(\alpha\otimes\beta)$ contains $\ker(\alpha)\otimes V_2+V_1\otimes \beta(V_2)$, and the kernel is no larger than this because the tensor product of subspaces can be identified with a subspace of the tensor product.
If $A\subseteq V_1, B\subseteq V_2$ we will write $A\otimes B$ for the set $\{a \otimes b: a\in A, b\in B\}$ (and similarly for subsets of $W_1,W_2$).
Proof: Pick a basis $S_1$ of $\ker(q_1)$ and extend it to  basis $B_1=S_1\sqcup T_1$ of $V_1$, and similarly pick a basis $S_2$ of $\ker(q_2)$ and extend it to a basis $B_2=S_2\sqcup T_2$ of $V_2$.  Then $\{b\otimes c: b \in B_1,c\in B_2\}$ is a basis of $V_1\otimes V_2$. The following claim is essentially a version of rank-nullity.
Claim 1: $\alpha(T_1)$ is a basis of $\alpha(V_1)$ and $\beta(T_2)$ is a basis of $\beta(V_2)$.
Proof: We check this for $\alpha$, the argument being identical for $\beta$. Since $\alpha(S_1)=0$ it is clear that $\alpha(V_1) = \text{Span}(\alpha(B_1)) = \text{span}(\alpha(T_1))$, so it remains to show $\alpha(T_1)$ is linearly independent. But if for some $\lambda_t \in F, (t \in T_1)$ we have $\sum_{t \in T_1} \lambda_t \alpha(t) =0$ then we have $\alpha(\sum_{t \in T_1} \lambda_t t)=0$ hence $\sum_{t \in T_1} \lambda_t t \in \ker(\alpha) = \text{span}(S_1)$ so that $\sum_{t \in T_1} \lambda_t t = \sum_{s \in S_1} \mu_s s$ for some scalars $\mu_s$ ($s \in S_1)$. Since $S_1\cup T_1 = B_1$ is a basis of $V_1$, it follows that $\lambda_t=\mu_s =0$ for all $t\in T_1$, $s\in S_1$.
Claim 2: $(\alpha\otimes \beta)(T_1\otimes T_2)=\alpha(T_1)\otimes \beta(T_2)$ is a basis of $\text{im}(\alpha\otimes \beta)$.
Proof: Since $B_1\otimes B_2$ is a basis of $V_1\otimes V_2$, it is clear that $\alpha(B_1)\otimes\beta(B_2)$ spans the image of $\alpha\otimes \beta$. But if $b\in S_1$ or $c\in S_2$ then $\alpha(b)\otimes \beta(c)=0$ (since $\otimes$ is bilinear) hence $\alpha(T_1)\otimes \beta(T_2)$ span the image of $\alpha\otimes \beta$. But $\alpha(T_1)$ and $\beta(T_2)$ are linearly independent sets and the tensor product of linearly independent sets is linearly independent (this is trivial to see using, for example, dual bases).
Finally, since $\alpha(T_1)\otimes \beta(T_2)$ is a basis of the image of $\alpha\otimes \beta$ and as already noted above,
$$
B_1\otimes B_2 \backslash T_1\otimes T_2 = S_1\otimes B_2 \cup B_1\otimes S_2\subset \ker(\alpha\otimes \beta)
$$
it follows that hence $S_1\otimes B_2 \cup B_1\otimes S_2$ is a basis for the kernel of $\alpha\otimes \beta$. Since it is clear that
$$
\text{span}(S_1\otimes B_2 \cup B_1\otimes S_2) = \ker(\alpha)\otimes V_2+ V_1\otimes \ker(\beta),
$$
the proof is complete.
